# Display relationships with 'WITH' clause Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to display the users whose sum of amount of transactions is greater than 5000
How do I display the relationship [:TRANS_AMOUNT] too.
My query

```
MATCH(c)-[r:TRANS_AMOUNT]->(e)
WITH sum(toInt(e.totalAmount))as l,c
WHERE l>5000
RETURN c,l;
```

The above query groups the sum by customer and checks if sum amount is greater than 5000. How do I display the relationships where this happens too?

Comment: have you tried to add `r` to your `return` clause?

Comment: Gives an error @Supamiu

Comment: Could you please add this error to your question?

Comment: Variable undefined @Supamiu

Answer (score 0):

Add the relationship to the `WITH` statement and return it:

```
MATCH (c)-[r:TRANS_AMOUNT]->(e)
WITH sum(toInt(e.totalAmount))as l, c, r
WHERE l>5000
RETURN c, l, r
```

You can also aggregate the relationships in order to have one row per user in the result:

```
MATCH (c)-[r:TRANS_AMOUNT]->(e)
WITH sum(toInt(e.totalAmount))as l, c, collect(r) as rels
WHERE l>5000
RETURN c, l, rels
```

Comment: You could group the relationships using `collect(r)`, to avoid returning as many rows as there are relationships. OP probably wants the aggregated collection anyway.

Comment: @MartinPreusse If I add the relationship in WITH clause, it groups the sum according to the edge too. Which I don't want

Comment: You can do the `collect()` in the `WITH` statement